# Prefer optional or non-optional when designing domain?

Tags: swift, model, option-type

While defining model for my application what properties should I declare as optional and what as non-optional? What aspects I need to consider?

E.g I want to create entity `Car`. What type `engine` should be?

```
struct Car {
    let engine: Engine?
}
```

or

```
struct Car {
    let engine: Engine

    init(engine: Engine) {
        self.engine = engine
    }
}
```

or

```
struct Car {
    let engine: Engine = Engine()
}
```

Comment: Will you have cars without engines? If yes, it should be an Optional so it can be nil. Otherwise, no. -- The key is to ask yourself, for every property: "does it make sense to be able to have nil here?" If the answer is yes, use an Optional.

Comment: @EricD another example. I have `Card` with `title` (`String` or `String?`), should absence of title be represented by `nil` or by `""` (empty string)

Comment: Absence of title is not "", this would be an *empty title*. The title exists but is empty. Absence of title would be a nil, preferably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Introduction

Many of us (me included) were not familiar with this problem.

Infact Objective-C (and many other languages like C, Java 1...7, etc...) forced a variable with a primitive type (Int, Double, ...) to **always** be populated.
And they also always forced a reference/pointer variable to **always be potentially nil**.
Se over the years we just adapted to these constraints.

Initially many Swift developers used implicitly unwrapped optionals

```
var something: Something!
```

This is the closest thing to declaring a reference variable in a way that behave similarly to the programming languages mentioned above but this way we don't really use the power of Optionals.

### When should I declare a property of my model as optional?

The question you have to ask yourself is

> In my data domain, can this entity exist and have no value for this specific property?

If the answer is **no**, then the property should be declared as **non optional**.

**Example**

A `User` struct representing the user of an app will always have a `username` and `password` populated.

```
struct User {
    let username: String
    let password: String
    let profileImageURL: NSURL?
}
```

On the other hand it could have a `nil` value for `profileImageURL` maybe because the user didn't upload a profile picture.

In this case a `User` value without a `username` just doesn't make sense, it can't happen and when dealing with a `User` value we should always have the guarantee (provided by the compiler) that there is `username` value in it.

So we make `username` non optional

### It really depends on the domain

The "optionality" of the property of an `Entity` can differ from data domain to data domain.

E.g. this entity for a mailing list system

```
struct Person {
    let name: String?
    let email: String
}
```

makes sense because we could not know the `name` but we know for sure its `email` address.

On the other hand the same entity in another context like an Address Book could become

```
struct Person {
    let name: String?
    let email: String?
}
```

because maybe we created/saved an empty card.

### Thumb of rule

As personal advice I suggest you to avoid optional values when you have doubts about it. If you declared a **non optional** property something that should actually be optional the problem will come up very soon.

On the other hand if you declared optional something that should be non optional you could never find out.

### Important

And of course NEVER use a value of the domain of the property/variable to represent the absence of value

```
let birthyear = -1 // 
let name = "" // 
let username = "NOT_PROVIDED" //
```